# Why toolbar's background color is maintained?

Tags: java, android

I changed colors of toolbar's background and its icon in one Activity.
but when I start other Activities, changed Colors is maintained....

```
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        binding.toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
        binding.toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.black,null));
        binding.toolbar.getOverflowIcon().setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.black,null));
        binding.toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.argb(0,255,255,255));
```

What is the problem??

Comment: Because toolbar is shared.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Set it again to whatever you require